# Is AccountId a valid field on Opportunity?

Tags: apex, opportunity, standard-objects, standard-field

In relation to the code below, is the "**AccountId**" a standard field in the opportunity object? I don't think the last code (acc.Id = opp.AccountId) is valid.

```
for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
    // Make sure we meet the minimum threshold
    if (opp.Amount >= OPP_MIN_VALUE) {
      // This is a trick to get the related account
      Account acc = new Account();
      acc.Id      = opp.**AccountId**;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see for yourself, `AccountId` is the first field listed in the [documentation on the **`Opportunity`** object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm).

No hard-coded reference to a field which does not exist will even compile.

```
Opportunity opp;
// loop record, for example

opp.BogusField = 'Some Value';
// this line will not compile

opp.put('DynamicField', 'Some Value');
// this line will compile but will cause a runtime error
// though it will work if you replace 'DynamicField' with a proper API Name
```